# Infinite dimensional integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. I would like to prove the following inequality:

$$\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left\lvert \int_0^t f(s, x)\,ds\right\rvert^q\, dx \right)^{\frac{1}{q}} \le \int_0^t \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert f(s, x)\rvert^q\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\, ds, $$

under the minimal assumption that all integrals make sense and the rightmost term above is finite. The idea was to rewrite the inequality this way

$$\left\lVert \int_0^t f(s,\cdot)\, ds\right\rVert_q \le \int_0^t \lVert f(s, \cdot) \rVert_q\, ds,$$

which looks so obviously true... But I'm afraid of some pitfall here. In fact, we cannot guarantee continuous dependence of $f$ on the first variable, so $\int_0^t f(s, \cdot)\, ds$ is not the usual Riemann integral in a Banach space.

What do you think: is this approach leading somewhere or I'd better try another one? (Which one, just in case? :-) )

**EDIT: Answer**
I've found a very satisfactory answer in Hardy-Littlewood-Polya's *Inequalities* (@Willie Wong: thank you!). I'm glad to expose it here (with slightly different language, in case you ask).

> **Theorem** Let $\Omega_t, \Omega_x$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $f \colon \Omega_t \times \Omega_x \to [0, \infty]$ be a measurable function. If $1 < p < \infty$ then 
>   $$\left\lVert \int_{\Omega_t} f(s, \cdot)\, ds\right\rVert_p \le \int_{\Omega_t}\lVert f(s, \cdot) \rVert_p \,ds,$$
>   where $\lVert \cdot \rVert_p$ refers to $L^p(\Omega_x)$.
>
> ---
>
> **Lemma** Let $\Omega$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $J \colon \Omega \to [0, \infty]$ a measurable function. If $1 < p < \infty$ and $F \ge 0$ then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\lVert J \rVert_p \le F$;
> 2. $\forall g \in L^{p'}(\Omega), g \ge 0, \int_{\Omega} g^{p'}dx \le 1$ we have $\int_{\Omega}Jg\, dx \le F$.

*Proof of Theorem*
Let $J(y)=\int_{\Omega_t}f(s, y)\, ds$. $J$ is a measurable positive function on $\Omega_x$. Take $g \in L^{p'}(\Omega_x), g \ge 0, \int_{\Omega_x}g(y)dy \le 1$. Then by Fubini's theorem and Hölder's inequality we have

$$\int_{\Omega_x}J(y)g(y)\, dy = \int_{\Omega_t}ds \int_{\Omega_x}f(s, y)g(y)dy\le \int_{\Omega_t}\left(\int_{\Omega_x}f(s, y)^p dy\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\, ds, $$

that is, $\int_{\Omega_x}J(y)g(y)dy\le \int_{\Omega_t} \lVert f(s, \cdot) \rVert_p\, ds$ and so $\lVert J \rVert_p \le \int_{\Omega_t} \lVert f(s, \cdot)\rVert_p\, ds$ by the lemma.    ////

The general principle here is very interesting: if you want to prove an inequality like $\int J^p\, dx \le \text{something}$, you can get past that annoying exponent $p$ by proving $\int Jg\, dx \le \text{something}$ for all suitable $g$.

*References* Hardy-Littlewood-Polya, *Inequalities*: my **Theorem** is their *Theorem 202*, my **Lemma** is their *Theorem 191*.

---

**EDIT 2020**

Let us see how to prove the Lemma. It looks MUCH tougher than it actually is. We don't actually need **any** functional analysis to prove it, no dual spaces or anything like that. The proof that 1. $\Rightarrow$ 2. is literally just an immediate application of the inequality of Hölder. The proof that 2. $\Rightarrow$ 1. is based on the obvious computation 
$$
\lVert J^{p-1}\rVert_{p'}=\lVert J\rVert_p^{p-1}, $$ 
which motivates us to write
$$
\lVert J\rVert_p^p=\lVert J\rVert_p^{p-1}\int J(x)\frac{J^{p-1}(x)}{\lVert J^{p-1}\rVert_{p'}}\, dx, $$ 
and now we can apply the assumption 2 to bound the integral, because $\frac{J^{p-1}(x)}{\lVert J^{p-1}\rVert_{p'}}$ has $p'$ norm equal to 1. We conclude
$$
\lVert J\rVert_p^p\le \lVert J\rVert_p^{p-1} F, $$ 
from which 1. immediately follows. $\Box$

*Remark*. As stressed by the book *Analysis* of Lieb and Loss, in the case of $L^p$ spaces the abstract functional analysis is not necessary, and it actually sometimes **obscures** what is going on. This is a good example of that phenomenon.

---

This edit comes nine years after the original question, one of my first ones. I am still here. Looks like I got hooked for real. :-)

Comment: Looks like the perfect occasion to learn about the [Bochner integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral).

Comment: For $t < \infty$, if the RHS is well defined, using Holder's inequality you have that $\int_0^t\int |f(s,x)| dx ds \leq $ C_t RHS. So your function is integrable in the product measure. By Fubini then $\int_0^tf(s,x)ds$ is (Lebesgue) measurable in $x$, and so the $L^q$ norm makes sense. BTW, the integral Minkowski's inequalities are theorems 200 - 202 in Hardy-Littlewood-Polya.

Comment: @Theo: Thank you! This makes for a quick and clean avenue of attack. @Willie Wong: I'm reading the direct proof of Hardy-Littlewood-Polya's *Inequalities*. I'm liking very much this idea of a book focused solely on inequalities. However, I find it a bit difficult to read because of unusual notation and typography. Can you give me some alternative reference a bit less...err... *dated*? I hope this does not sound too much of a blasphemy.

Comment: Does your "this looks so obviously true" not follow from an application of Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @dissonance Do yourself a favor and get Michael Steele's *The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class*. You won't regret it!

Comment: @Glen: essentially yes. If I understand correctly, $f$ is supposed to be a measurable function $f: \mathbb{R} \times \Omega \to X$ where $\Omega$ is some measure space and $X$ some Banach space.

Comment: @Glen, @Theo: Yes, sorry, I didn't specify. $f$ is a function of time and space, that is, $f \colon \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There's also a proof in F. Jones' _Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space_, Section 11.E.

Comment: @dissonance: sorry to disappoint, but Hardy-Littlewood-Polya did such a bang-up job that I don't have any other references handy. Fortunately, other people do. Good luck!

Comment: @dissonance: I like your approach but maybe it is a little bit overkill.

Comment: @Jonas: You're right, I agree that this is an inequality that must be proven "by hand". We have here more or less the same difficulty than in Minkowsky's inequality. I think it is no coincidence that your technique works for that inequality, too.

Comment: Your "general principle" is precisely the fact that the natural embedding $L^p \hookrightarrow (L^{p'})^*$ is an isometry.

Comment: @NateEldredge At first glance, I also thought of this. But when I tried to prove "$2\Rightarrow 1$" by using the Riesz representation theorem, i.e. the natural embedding you mentioned, I realized that, in the assumption of statement $2$, we didn't know if $J$ was in $L^p$, and what's worse, it required that $g\ge 0$. On the closed unit ball in $L^{p^\prime}$, we may not have $g\ge 0$. So I think this inequality is not as trivial as we thought.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Hi Giuseppe, I am having a trouble with proving the direction of $"2\Rightarrow 1"$ in your lemma. I tried to read the text written by Hardy etc., but the symbols were too old to follow. Can you help me out with this proof? Thanks.

Comment: @SamWong: I edited the question. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro LMAO, thanks for your quick response. But there remains a problem that $J$ may not be in $L^p$, which makes your auxiliary function $\frac{J^{p-1}(x)}{\lVert J^{p-1}\rVert_{p'}}$ may not be well defined.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I started a question about the proof of this lemma in this afternoon (c.f. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563058/help-with-proving-this-lemma/3563085?noredirect=1#comment7326398_3563085). Now the problem is reduced to prove that $J\in L^p$, and @Mick(who is the one answered my question) and me are trying to prove this.

Comment: Do you really need to do that? I mean, if $J\notin L^p$, then $\lVert J\rVert_p=\infty$ and everything holds trivially with $F=\infty$. Oh, it is true that in $2$ you need to play a little bit with some sequences.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yeah, there will be a hard time if $J\notin L^p$, while Mick has worked out this tough question in my post. Thanks for the motivation by the lemma from your post as well as your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first thing to try is to set

$$f(x,t) = \sum_{j = 1}^N g_j(x) 1_{F_j}(y)$$

for pairwise disjoint $F_j$. For this the inequality is easy to verify.

Now we would like to take limits, but the question is: Are the measurable functions pointwise limits of function of the form of $f$? It turns out this is the case as has been shown by Nate Eldredge on a question of mine (I tried to prove the same). [Sequence of measurable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5648/sequence-of-measurable-functions)