# Mixed Lebesgue spaces: information needed

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega_t$ and $\Omega_x$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. If it makes things easier we can assume that $\Omega_t$ is some interval and $\Omega_x$ some Euclidean space. For each measurable $f\colon \Omega_t \times \Omega_x \to \mathbb{C}$ define

$$\lVert f(t, x) \rVert_{L^p_t L^q_x}=\left[\int_{\Omega_t}dt \left(\int_{\Omega_x} \lvert f(t, x) \rvert^q\, dx\right)^\frac{p}{q}\right]^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

I would like to get some information on the resulting space $L^p_t L^q_x(\Omega_t \times \Omega_x)$, especially:

- Under what name is it known?
- Is it the product of some canonical construction? Is there some *obvious* way to show that it is complete (if true)?
- Is there any relationship between $\lVert f(t, x) \rVert_{L^p_t L^q_x}$ and $\lVert f(t, x) \rVert_{L^q_x L^p_t}$? Under what circumstances do they coincide?

I'm especially after some reference, but answers of any other kind (proofs, hints, conjectures) are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: (BTW, if you don't get any useful answers after a while, you may consider asking this on MathOverflow.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For point 1 (nomenclature): sometimes you see them called *anisotropic Lebesgue spaces*, and sometimes in the partial differential equations literature you see them called *Strichartz spaces*. Most of the time no names are given, and in the PDE context they are almost exclusively studied on $\Omega_t = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Omega_x = \mathbb{R}^m$ (or subsets thereof) with Lebesgue measure. A while back I did some literature search, and unfortunately didn't find much myself outside the PDE literature on these spaces.

For point 2 (completeness): maybe through Banach-space valued functions? I haven't actually thought too hard about this.

For point 3 (reversing order of integration): they generally don't coincide (using Minkowski's inequality you can show that one embeds into the other when $p\neq q$, and a counterexample for the reversed inequality will extend to a counterexample of the reverse embedding), except when $p = q$, which follows from Fubini. Note that in certain cases (for example the $\ell^p$ norm on finite dimensional vector spaces interpreted as an atomic measure on $n$ points) the global equivalence of $L^p$ and $L^q$ as norms would imply the coincidence of the spaces, so any characterisation needs to have some additional hypotheses.

Comment: 1) Strichartz spaces, ok! In fact (as you surely have guessed from what I'm asking those days) I'm studying Strichartz estimates for the Schrödinger equation. [...]

Comment: 2) I will think about it a little. My guess is that they are Banach spaces and that we have the representation $[L^p_tL^q_x]'\equiv L^{p'}_tL^{q'}_x$. This would justify the terminology $T, T^\star, TT^\star$ that I see in my course notes. [...]

Comment: 3) Ok. I guess that for PDE use it is most important to take the spacial norm first. By Minkowski's inequality you mean [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/33659/8157), right?

Comment: For (2) you should see lvb's answer. There's still some grunt work to be done (showing that $f$ can be interpreted as a measurable function with values in a Banach space). For (3), yes.

Answer (score 4):

The spaces $L^p_tL^q_x$ are special cases of the more general [Bochner spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space) $L^p(\Omega;X)$ which are Banach spaces in general and whose dual space is given by $L^{p^\prime}(\Omega;X^\prime)$ for $1<p<\infty$ whenever $X$ has the *Radon-Nikodym property*, e.g. if $X$ is reflexive.

A very good treatment of these spaces and the Bochner integral is given for instance in [Vector-valued Laplace Transforms and Cauchy Problems](http://books.google.de/books?id=5mcf0Xmuq-0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=vector-valued%20laplace%20transforms%20and%20cauchy%20problems&source=bl&ots=fPumPCiH0i&sig=w8Pf8s3DPp1xlz97Rco89Rxfyok&hl=de&ei=4wG3TbTtOs3oOeyomYIP&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=vector-valued%20laplace%20transforms%20and%20cauchy%20problems&f=false) by Arendt, Batty, Hieber, Neubrander.

As far as I know, one can also interprete $L^p(\Omega;X)$ as (projective) tensor product of $L^p(\Omega)$ and $X$.

**Edit:** The last paragraph only holds for $p=1$, see the comments below.

Comment: The last paragraph is incorrect. for instance, one can show that the diagonal of $\ell^2 \hat{\otimes}_{\pi} \ell^2$ is a complemented subspace isomorphic to $\ell^1$. However, $\ell^2(\mathbb{N},\ell^2)$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't too sure about that either. I'm pretty sure, though, that the last paragraph holds at least for $p=1$.

Comment: Yes, that's true (this is not hard to show by using that the step functions are dense and isometric in both $L^1(\Omega,X)$ and $L^1(\Omega) \hat{\otimes}_{\pi} X$). I think Grothendieck was the first to observe this. There are tensor norms compatible with $L^p$ but I can't seem to remember their name.

Comment: Do you recall any reference for $L^p$-compatible tensor product constructions?

Comment: I think there is something to that effect in C. Herz, *The theory of $p$-spaces* (or a similar title. I can't access MathSciNet at the moment). I might misremember, though. Quite probably things are more subtle. There are also things related to the Lindenstrauss-Pelczinsky $\mathcal{L}_p$-spaces, see e.g. in Ryan and references therein (but again, things are more subtle than one might wish for).

Comment: I've found the paper. Its full title is _The theory of $p$-spaces and applications to convolution operators_ by Carl Herz. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this must be the paper I had in mind.