# Extend an integral inequality from $C[0,1]$ to the whole $L^{2}([0,1])$ [related to operator norm].

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Consider the following integral defined for $f\in L^{2}[0,1]$ and $x\in [0,1]$, that $$(T^{n}f)(x)=\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{x}(x-r)^{n-1}f(r)dr.$$

This shows that for $f\in C[0,1]$ and for any $x\in [0,1]$, we have $$|(T^{n}f)(x)|\leq \dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{x}(x-r)^{n-1}|f(r)|dr\leq \dfrac{\|f\|_{\infty}}{n!}.$$ By definition of operator norm, this implies that the operator norm of $T^{n}$ $$\|T^{n}\|\leq \dfrac{1}{n!},$$ if the operator is on $C[0,1]$.

---

However, I want to prove the same bound of this operator norm on the whole $L^{2}([0,1])$.  Is there anyway for me to extend this proof to all of $f\in L^{2}([0,1])$? and to conclude $\|T^{n}\|\leq\frac{1}{n!}$

My attempt was to use density of continuous function of compact support in $L^{2}$ to find $g$ such that $f=g+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrarily fixed. Then we bound the integral in the same way, and you will have a summation, the second term in the summation will go to $0$ when $\epsilon\searrow 0$. Therefore, we again have $$|(T^{n}f)(x)|\dfrac{\|g\|_{\infty}}{n!}.$$  But this cannot say anything to the operator norm $\|T\|$.

What should I do? Thank you!

**Edit:**

The overall purpose is to derive that $\|T\|\leq\frac{1}{n!}$. So if there is any other way to find this, it will also be really good.

**Edit2: Proof**

Okay, I confused myself in the first place. The operator norm has nothing to do with the sup-norm since $T:L^{2}\longrightarrow L^{2}$, so what we should do is to use Cauchy-Schwarz and $\|f\|_{L^{2}}$. See below my own answer to my post for details.

Also, Ruy gave a general theorem about how to compute the operator norm for Hilbert-Schmidt operator, and my computation will show you the idea about the proof. Basically, the absolute value of operator will be bounded by $\|f\|_{L^{2}}$ multiplication of the $L^{2}-$integral of the kernel, so we should expect such a theorem.

Thank you so much for all the users who helped me!!

Comment: You could say something if you had an estimate of $\frac{\lVert T^nf\rVert_\infty}{\lVert f\rVert_2}$, because the tautological embedding $L^\infty[0,1]\hookrightarrow L^2[0,1]$ has norm $1$, but if you leave the $\lVert f\rVert_\infty$ in the denominator I doubt you'll go anywhere. That being said, there might not even be an estimate of $\lVert \bullet\rVert_\infty/\lVert \bullet\rVert_2$.

Comment: @Gae.S. okay so there is another way for me to prove $\|T\|\leq\frac{1}{n!}$?

Comment: Well, you have to find an estimate of $\lVert T(\bullet)\rVert_2/\lVert \bullet\rVert_2$. You can do this on whatever dense subset of $L^2[0,1]$ you want. I don't quite know what you could choose, but that is the closest to a reasonable idea I can find.

Comment: In the first line you have $(x-r)^{n-1}$ and in the second $(x-r)^n$, is this right? Also,  are you looking for the operator norm as an operator $L^2\to L^2$?

Comment: In addition, you seem to have used $\|\int_0^1 K(x-r) f(r) dr \|_{L^p} \le \|K\|_{L^1} \|f\|_{L^p}$ for $p=\infty$. But this inequality is valid for all $p\in[1,\infty]$; its essentially just [generalised Minkowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski's_integral_inequality), see e.g. [here for a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355672/prove-minkowskis-inequality-for-integrals) (though you should change variables so that its $\int_0^1 K(r) f(x-r) dr$ inside

Comment: @CalvinKhor Sorry for the late reply. I mean $(x-r)^{n-1}$ all the time, I will edit the post. Yes, I am looking for operator norm as an operator $L^{2}\longrightarrow L^{2}$. Yes, we can use generalized Minkowski, but it is not necessarily true that $f\in L_{\infty}$, right?

Comment: @CalvinKhor the inequality was from peter lax page page 230, but by a second thought I am not sure why it is true... let me think about it and try to edit the post

Comment: @CalvinKhor sorry for the multiple reply. I just realized that I should use $\|f\|_{2}$ to bound, since the operator is from $L_{2}$ to $L_{2}$, not to $C[0,1]$, so I guess using Schwartz is enough.  I will edit my post or answer my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given  $k\in L^2([0, 1]\times[0, 1])$,
one may define an operator $A_k$ on $L^2([0, 1])$ by
$$
  A_k(f)|_x  = \int_0^1 k(x, y)f(y)\,  dy, \quad \forall f\in  L^2([0, 1]), \quad \forall x\in [0,1].
  $$

This is called an *integral operator* and $k$ is said to be its *integral kernel*.

Besides being bounded, $A_k$ is Hilbert-Schmidt, and its Hilbert-Schmidt norm $\|A_k\|_2$ may be computed as
$$
  \|A_k\|_2 = \left(\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |k(x, y)|^2 \, dx\,  dy\right)^{1/2}.
  $$
See [1,Theorem VI.23] for details.

Since the operator norm is always bounded by the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, one may use the above to estimate the former.

The operator $T^n$ mentioned by the OP is clearly an example of the above, where
$$
  k(x, r)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(x-r)^{n-1}[r\leq x],
  $$
where $[r\leq x]$ takes the values 1 or 0 according to whether $r\leq x$ or not.

If my calculations are correct this method provides an even better estimate for the norm of $T^n$.

---

[1] *Reed, Michael; Simon, Barry*, Methods of modern mathematical physics. I: Functional analysis. Rev. and enl. ed, New York etc.: Academic Press, A Subsidiary of Harcourt Brace Jovanovich, Publishers, XV, 400 p. $ 24.00 (1980). [ZBL0459.46001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0459.46001).

---

**EDIT**:
OK, prompted by Calvin Khor's challenge, here is the full calculation based on the Hilbert-Schmidt norm and leading to a slightly better estimate.

I will temporarily ignore the coefficient $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ since it doesn't play much of a role in the computation, so
let us first
deal with
$$
  h(x, r)=(x-r)^{n-1}[r\leq x].
  $$
We then have
$$
  \|A_h\|_2^2 =
  \int_0^1 \int_0^1 |h(x, r)|^2 \, dr\,  dx =
  \int_0^1 \int_0^1 |(x-r)^{n-1}[r\leq x]|^2 \, dr\,  dx = $$$$ =
  \int_0^1 \int_0^x (x-r)^{2n-2} \, dr\,  dx =
   \int_0^1 \frac{-(x-r)^{2n-1}}{2n-1} \Big|_0^x\,  dx = $$$$ =
   \int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}\,  dx =
   \frac{x^{2n}}{2n(2n-1)}\Big|_0^1 =
   \frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}.
  $$
This implies that
$$
  \|A_k\| \leq
  \|A_k\|_2 =
  \frac{1}{(n-1)!}  \|A_h\|_2 =
  \frac{1}{(n-1)!\sqrt{2n(2n-1)}}.
  $$
So we indeed get a better estimate than just   $\frac{1}{n!}$ because
$$
  \sqrt{2n(2n-1)} \geq    \sqrt{(2n-1)^2} = 2n-1 \geq  n.
  $$

**Remark**.  Since the Hilbert-Schmidt norm is usually much bigger than the operator norm, there is still a lot of room for
improvement.  Any bidders? :-)

Comment: Nice. Although I have computed the bound, your answer gave a general approach. Thank you! I will also edit my post to show the exact bound.

Comment: I am sorry but do you mind showing your bound? Like, in my computation, I have \begin{align*}
\Big|(T^{n}f)(x)\Big|^{2}\leq \Bigg(\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{x}|x-r|^{n-1}|f(r)|dr\Bigg)^{2}&=\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\Bigg)^{2}\Bigg(\int_{0}^{x}|x-r|^{n-1}|f(r)|dr\Bigg)^{2}\\
&\leq\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\Bigg)^{2}\|f\|_{L^{2}([0,1])}^{2}\int_{0}^{x}|x-r|^{2n-2}dr,
\end{align*} but I don't know how to evaluate $\int_{0}^{x}|x-r|^{2n-2}dr$ so that it can give me $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$

Comment: Since $2n-2$ is even one has that $|x-r|^{2n-2}=(x-r)^{2n-2}$, so the primitive is easy to find.

Comment: Yes, so we have $$\int_{0}^{x}|x-r|^{2n-2}dr=\int_{0}^{x}(x-r)^{2n-2}dr=-\dfrac{1}{2n-1}\Big[(x-r)^{2n-1}\Big]_{0}^{x}=\dfrac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1},$$ but how to get $\frac{1}{n^{2}}?$ It's like $\dfrac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$ is not always bounded by $\frac{1}{n^{2}}.$ The only bound I am sure is $\dfrac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}\leq\frac{1}{n}$, as $n\geq 2$. Seems like I get a weaker bound since then $\|T\|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n-1)!}\geq\frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: The 2-norm of the integral kernel involves a **double** integral!

Comment: Yes you are right. I just want to try to bound it in my way, but I guess its okay, since in the end I want to show the radius of the spectrum is $0$, and my worse bound seems not affecting the decay. Thank you so much!

Comment: By computing the missing integral you would get a better bound.  But I see you are already happy with what you got.

Answer (score 2):

Just promoting my comments to an answer because it gives the constant that appears in the question; Ruy gives a (better) method that works for more general kernels, but the kernel here is nice (it is continuous, bounded, $L^1$, ...) so we can apply [generalised Minkowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski%27s_integral_inequality) as follows:

\begin{align}\left\| \int_{0}^x K(r) f(x-r)dr\right\|_{L^p([0,1])} 
&\le \int_0^1 \|K(r)f(x-r)\mathbf 1_{r<x}\|_{L^p (x\in[0,1])}dr 
\\
&= \int_0^1|K(r)| \|f(x-r)\mathbf1_{r<x}\|_{L^p  (x\in[0,1])}dr
\\
&\le \|K\|_{L^1([0,1])}\|f\|_{L^p([0,1])}. \end{align}
So the operator norm is at most
$$\|K\|_{L^1(0,1)}=\frac{\int_0^1r^{n-1}dr}{(n-1)!}=\frac1{n!}.$$

Comment: Hey Calvin, can you beat $\frac{1}{(n-1)!\sqrt{2n(2n-1)}}$ :-)  Please see my edit above!

Comment: @Ruy haha it wasn’t a challenge but good to see that there is an improvement!

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Just upvoted! Yes, generalized Minkowski is really useful. I should have used it, but as my stupid question in the comment, I mistreated $T:L_2\longrightarrow C[0,1]$, but it actually should be $T:L_2\longrightarrow L_2$, so the generalized Minkowski is used as $p=2$. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to say that, thanks to @Calvin, I have just learned about the generalized Minkowski inequality.  Thanks very much!

Comment: You’re welcome! In fact once you prove $\| \|f\|_{L^1_x} \|_{L^p_y} \le \| \|f\|_{L^p_y} \|_{L^1_x} $ you actually get $\| \|f\|_{L^q_x} \|_{L^p_y} \le \| \|f\|_{L^p_y} \|_{L^q_x} $ for all $q\le p$ for free! It’s just some cute applications of $\| |f|^a \|_{L^b} = \| f \|^a_{L^{ab}}$

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I guess in my way we will not be able to finally get $\frac{1}{n!}$, but a little bit worse bound $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n-1)!}$, but it does not affect the general decaying I need in the end, so it is okay.

The following is my proof:

The $n-$fold iterate of $T$ is given by the formula $$(T^{n}f)(x)=\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{x}(x-r)^{n-1}f(r)dr.$$ This implies that, for $f\in L^{2}([0,1])$, by Cauchy-Schwarz, we have the following:
\begin{align*}
\Big|(T^{n}f)(x)\Big|^{2}\leq \Bigg(\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{x}|x-r|^{n-1}|f(r)|dr\Bigg)^{2}&=\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\Bigg)^{2}\Bigg(\int_{0}^{x}|x-r|^{n-1}|f(r)|dr\Bigg)^{2}\\
&\leq\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\Bigg)^{2}\|f\|_{L^{2}([0,1])}^{2}\int_{0}^{x}|x-r|^{2n-2}dr,
\end{align*}
and  $$\int_{0}^{x}|x-r|^{2n-2}dr=\int_{0}^{x}(x-r)^{2n-2}dr=-\dfrac{1}{2n-1}\Big[(x-r)^{2n-1}\Big]_{0}^{x}=\dfrac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}.$$ As $x\in [0,1]$ and $n\geq 2$, we further have $$\int_{0}^{x}|x-r|^{2n-2}dr=\dfrac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}\leq \dfrac{1}{2n-1}\leq \dfrac{1}{n}.$$

Hence, $$|(T^{n}f)(x)|\leq \dfrac{\|f\|_{L^{2}([0,1])}}{\sqrt{n}(n-1)!},$$ and by definition of the operator norm of our operator $T:L^{2}([0,1])\longrightarrow L^{2}([0,1])$, this implies that $$\|T^{n}\|\leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n-1)!}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are satisfied with a weaker bound $\frac1{\sqrt{n}(n-1)!}$ then we can use Cauchy-Schwarz on the $\|T^nf\|_\infty$ estimate:

\begin{align}
\|T^nf\|_2 &\le \|T^nf\|_\infty \\
&\le \frac1{(n-1)!} \sup_{x\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 |x-r|^{n-1}|f(r)|\,dr\\
&\le \frac1{(n-1)!} \sqrt{\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 |x-r|^{2n-1}\,dr} \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f(r)|^2\,dr}\\
&= \frac1{(n-1)!} \sqrt{\frac1{2n-1}}\|f\|_2\\
&\le \frac1{\sqrt{n}(n-1)!}\|f\|_2.
\end{align}

Comment: yes. exactly what I did. Thank you so much! This also confirmed my solution. Nice