# Integral for Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Trying to prove Minkowski's inequality

$$\int dy \bigg[  \int f(x,y)^p dx\bigg]^{1/p} \geq \bigg[ \int dx \bigg(\int f(x,y)dy\bigg)^p\bigg]^{1/p}$$

Comment: The inequality you've given is not the usual Minkowski inequality, are you certain about what you've written?

Comment: you're right sorry fixed the op

Comment: I think you're mixing the positions of the $p$-power in the left and right hand sides.

Comment: sorry thanks again. edited the op

Comment: You are assuming that all functions that occur are non-negative?

Comment: yes for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ and all functions finite and integrable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prove Minkowski's Inequality for Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355672/prove-minkowskis-inequality-for-integrals)

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach using Fubini-Tonelli and Hölder's inequality. It does not use the triangle inequality.

We define $h(x) := \int_{\Omega_1} f(x,y) \mathrm{d}y$
for all $x \in \Omega_2$.
We have to estimate
$\|h\|_p$.
We take an arbitrary
$g \in L^{q}(\Omega_2)$
and get
\begin{align*}
 \int_{\Omega_2} h(x) g(x) \mathrm{d}x
 &=
 \int_{\Omega_2} \int_{\Omega_1} f(x,y) g(x) \mathrm{d} y \mathrm{d} x
 \\
 &=
 \int_{\Omega_1} \int_{\Omega_2} f(x,y) g(x) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} y
 \\
 &\le
 \int_{\Omega_1}
 \left(\int_{\Omega_2} f(x,y)^p \mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}
 \left(\int_{\Omega_2} g(x)^{q} \mathrm{d} x\right)^{1/q}
 \mathrm{d} y
 \\
 &=
 \int_{\Omega_1}
 \left(\int_{\Omega_2} f(x,y)^p \mathrm{d} x\right)^{1/p}
 \mathrm{d} y
 \|g\|_{q}
 .
\end{align*}
Here, we used the Fubini-Tonelli theorem
and Hölders inequality.
Now,
\begin{equation*}
 \|h\|_p
 =
 \sup_{\|g\|_{q} \le 1}
 \int_{\Omega_2} h(x) g(x) \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
yields
$$
\left( \int_{\Omega_2}\left(\int_{\Omega_1} f(x,y) \mathrm{d}y\right)^p \mathrm dx \right)^{1/p}
=
\|h\|_p \le \int_{\Omega_1}
 \left(\int_{\Omega_2} f(x,y)^p \mathrm{d} x\right)^{1/p}
 \mathrm{d} y 
$$

Comment: sorry how does the last step give us the estimate? I think my idea was to write the LHS as $\int dy [\int f(x,y)^p dx]^{1/p} = \int dy \sup_{||g(x,y)||_Lq \leq 1} \int f(x,y)g(x,y) dx$ but im a little stuck with how to do that for the RHS

Comment: I have added some more terms. Does it help?

Comment: I get it up to the very last step how do we know that LHS = $||h||_p$?

Comment: Also is there a typo in the LHS should it be $\bigg( \int \bigg(\int f(x,y)dy\bigg)^p dx\bigg)^{1/p}$?

Comment: The last step is just the definition of $\|h\|_p$. And yes, an integral was missing on the left-hand side.