# Does the $\log$-$\exp$ analogous of Minkowski integral inequality hold true?

Tags: convex-analysis, integral-inequality, holder-inequality, convexity-inequality

Suppose that $X$ is a $\mathcal{X}$-valued random variable and $Y$ is a $\mathcal{Y}$-valued random variable.

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent of each other.

Suppose that $f: \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y} \to [0,+\infty]$ is a measurable function.

[Minkowski integral inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski%27s_integral_inequality) implies that for any $p\ge 1$ it holds that
$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\Big(\mathbb{E}\big[f(X,Y)^p \mid Y\big]\Big)^{1/p}\bigg] \ge \Bigg(\mathbb{E}\bigg[\Big(\mathbb{E}\big[f(X,Y) \mid X\big]\Big)^{p}\bigg]\Bigg)^{1/p}$$

Here, defining $\varphi:z \mapsto z^p$ and $\psi:z \mapsto z^{1/p}$, we see that $\varphi$ is convex, $\psi$ is concave, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are inverses of each other, and Minkowski integral inequality tells us that
$$\mathbb{E}\Bigg[\psi\bigg(\mathbb{E}\Big[\varphi\big(f(X,Y)\big) \mid Y\Big]\bigg)\Bigg] \ge \psi\Bigg(\mathbb{E}\bigg[\varphi\Big(\mathbb{E}\big[f(X,Y) \mid X\big]\Big)\bigg]\Bigg)$$
I suspect the convexity of $\varphi$, the concavity of $\psi$, and being them inverses of each other are insufficient to guarantee that the previous inequality holds true in general... On the other hand, I'm interested in two specific functions: does the same inequality hold true replacing $\varphi$ and $\psi$ with $\bar{\varphi}:z \mapsto \exp(z)$ and $\bar{\psi}:z\mapsto \log(z)$, respectively? I.e., does it hold true that:

$$\mathbb{E}\Bigg[\log\bigg(\mathbb{E}\Big[\exp\big(f(X,Y)\big) \mid Y\Big]\bigg)\Bigg] \ge\log\Bigg(\mathbb{E}\bigg[\exp\Big(\mathbb{E}\big[f(X,Y) \mid X\big]\Big)\bigg]\Bigg) \;?$$

The proof I know along which Minkowski integral inequality is proven ([i.e., relying on Holder inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3738061/233540)) doesn't seem to work (since I don't see any analogous inequality to rely on here).

Is the suggested inequality utterly wrong? Or if it seems plausible, does anyone have an idea on how to attack the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof of the fact that the suggested log-exp Minkowski inequality is true can be found in the Appendix B of this paper: https://hal.science/hal-04383576