# Integral of an $L^p(\mathbb R^2)$ function is in $L^p(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb R^2)$ for all $p\in[1,\bar p)$. Consider
$$ g(y):=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x,y)\,dx \;.$$
Can I say that $g\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ for the same values of  $p$ ?

Comment: Hint: [Minkowski integral inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33659/8157).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro if I understand correctly, this is triangular inequality for integrals. So I get $$\|g\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)} \leq \int_{\mathbb R}\|f(x,\cdot)\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}\,d x \;.$$ But it is not guarantee that the r.h.s. integral is finite for $p>1$, am I wrong?