# Limit of the $L^p$ norm of a simple function as $p\to 0^+$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $\phi:[0,1] \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is a simple function, please give me a hint for how to calculate this limit:  $$\lim_{p\to 0^+}\|\phi\|_p$$

Comment: Hint: start with the simplest case. What happens if $f$ is constant? Try to generalize from there.

Comment: After the constant, then do the case where $\phi$ has two values.  Perhaps it will be easier to generalize from that than from the constant case.

Comment: I proved a more general case [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/282311/4583).

Comment: @Ayman Hourieh:Thanks. therefore we have  $\lim_{p\to 0^+}||\phi||_p=e^{\int log\phi} $

Comment: Yes. Try to prove it where $\phi$ has two values as GEdgar suggested. You'll arrive at this result. If you get stuck, edit your question and we will help.