# Convergence of $L^p$ norm as $p \downarrow 0$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, lp-spaces

Consider a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ with $P(\Omega) = 1$. Define for measurable functions $X$ the following $\| X \|_p := \left(\int |X|^p dP\right)^{1/p}$. We know that for $p \in [1, \infty)$  that this is a norm, the $L^p$ norm. Let $S = \{p : 0 < p < \infty \text{ and } \|X \|_p <\infty \}$ and assume that $S \neq \emptyset$. Prove
$$
\lim_{p \downarrow 0} \| X \|_p = \exp \{ \int \log |X| \; dP  \}
$$
defining $\exp\{ - \infty \} := 0$.

Disclaimer: This *was* a homework problem in a graduate measure theory. The teacher never distributed solutions, and I have struggled to prove it since I first saw it.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/282311/4583) for a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Jensens Inequality and the $log(\dots)$ as the convex function