# what is the limit of $l_p$ at p=0?

Tags: limits, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

The p-norm is defined as:

$$ \ \|x\|_p=\left(|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p+\dotsb+|x_n|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} $$

When $p<1$, this is no longer a "norm" because it violates the triangle inequality (- it is super additive and not subadditive). However, it is still valid to ask, what is its limit when p goes to 0?

My guess is that:

- If all coordinates are 0, then $l_p=0$, and it remains like this when p=0.
- If exactly one coordinate, say $x_i$, is non-zero, then $l_p=x_i$, and it remains like this when p=0.
- If more than one coordinate (say, $x_i$ and $x_j$) are non-zero, then $l_p>x_i$, and because the exponent goes to $\infty$, the value of $l_p$ also goes to $\infty$.

Is this correct?

(Note that this is not equal to the [$l_0$ "norm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L0_norm#Zero_norm) = the number of nonzero elements. This is also not equal to the [scaled norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282271/scaled-lp-norm-and-geometric-mean), in which there is an additional $1/n$ factor).

Comment: If $n\gt1$, then
$$
\left(|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p\right)^{1/p}\to n^{1/p}\to\infty
$$
so yes, you are correct.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282271/scaled-lp-norm-and-geometric-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guesses are all correct.  In particular, the limit is $+\infty$ if there are two or more nonzero components.

Suppose WLOG that $x_1\neq 0$ and $x_2\neq 0$, and that $|x_1|\leq |x_2|$. Then $\|x\|_p\geq 2^{1/p}|x_1|\to +\infty$ as $p\searrow 0$.