# If $f\in L^{p_0}[0,1]$, $p_0$ is a given number big enough. Prove: $\lim_{p \to 0+}\Vert f\Vert_p=e^{\int_0^1 \ln\vert f(x)\vert dx}.$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

> **Problem:** if $f\in L^{p_0}[0,1]$, $p_0$ is a given number big enough. Prove: $$\lim_{p \to 0+}\Vert f\Vert_p=e^{\int_0^1 \ln\vert f(x)\vert dx}~.$$

I've proved one side of the equation by using Jensen's Inequality: we have
$$-\ln (\int_0^1 \vert f\vert^p dx)\le\int_0^1-\ln\vert f\vert^pdx,$$
then we have $$\Vert f\Vert_p\ge e^{\int_0^1 \ln\vert f(x)\vert dx}.$$
Now I have trouble sovling the other side of the euqation. Could anyone help me solve the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282271/scaled-lp-norm-and-geometric-mean/282311#282311) could also solve the problem!